# How to get the second to the last item in combobox

Tags: vb.net

So I have a combobox which gets its value in a database, at first I only need the last value inside the combobx in which i used

Dim lastitem As Integer = 0

```
lastitem = ClassInfo.ComboBox1.Items.Count
ClassInfo.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = lastitem - 1
```

Btw I'm creating an enrollment system in which the system will automatically detects the previous year for the new enrollees to be added in the the current year, since every year is changing i need to know how to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you get the last item by subtracting 1 from the `Count`, how is it not obvious that you subtract 2 to get the second last item?

Comment: Woow. Thanks a lot mate. my brain didn't work for a second. Sweet.